# Infinite While Loop in Python 2

Tags: python, while-loop

```
file = open(r'd:\holiday_list.txt', 'w')
date = ''
while(date != '0'):
    date = input('\nEnter Date (YYYYMMDD) : ')
    date = date[:4] + '-' + date[4:6] + '-' + date[5:]
    file.write(date)
print('Job Done!')
file.close()
```

This program is supposed to take dates (eg:20112016) as input and write it to a file.
The problem is the program does not exit the while loop. If i enter a 0, it prompts me to enter another date.

Comment: The line `date = date[:4] + '-' + date[4:6] + '-' + date[5:]` modifies the '0' to '0--'.

Answer (score 2):

You have your check in the wrong place: you manipulate the date as soon as you read it in, and the result is no longer `'0'` when you get back to the top of the loop.  Try this:

```
date = input('\nEnter Date (YYYYMMDD) : ')
while(date != '0'):
    date = date[:4] + '-' + date[4:6] + '-' + date[5:]
    file.write(date)
    date = input('\nEnter Date (YYYYMMDD) : ')
```

ANother check is the most basic of debugging: put in a `print` command to show *exactly* what you read in.  Perhaps something like

```
print("date is ||", date"||")
```

The vertical bars will show any leading or trailing white space, such as the newline character.  (Get rid of that with the `strip` method.)

Comment: this works. the dates are qetting appended to one line though in thee text file. eg. 0401-19-9910408-19-989. I can add a new line. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to Prune's is to use an `if` statement with a `break`:

```
    while(True):
        date=input('\nEnter Date (YYYYMMDD) : ')
        if(date=='0'):
            break
        ...#your work here
```

This way you don't have to have an additional input outside the loop.

Comment: ... but you have an extra check in your logic.  It's a style trade-off.

Comment: Indeed, it's more of a personal choice.